# Passing Auth User data To Queue Job Class

Tags: php, laravel, jobs

I've created a job that processes PDFs in the background. I would like to fire off an email to the Auth user once the job is complete with a link to download the newly generated PDF.

Here is what I'm currently doing.

**Controller:**

```
        public function haitiKidPdfAll(){
            $pdfUser = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $haitiKids = Kid::
            whereRaw('sponsors_received < sponsors_needed')
            ->where('current_country', 'Haiti')
            ->orderBy('sponsors_received', 'ASC')
            ->get();

            ProcessPdfHaiti::dispatch($haitiKids,$pdfUser);
            return back()->with('info','This will take a couple minutes. I\'ll email you when it\'s completed.');
```

**ProcessPdfHaiti Job:**

> Get Error Here: Undefined variable: pdfUser {"exception":"[object]
>   (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: pdfUser at line 53.
>   which is `$pdfUserEmail =  $pdfUser->email;` In the code below.

```
class ProcessPdfHaiti implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $haitiKids;
    public $pdfUser;

    public function __construct($haitiKids,$pdfUser)
    {
        $this->haitiKids = $haitiKids;
        $this->pdfUser = $pdfUser;
    }

    public function handle()
    {

        ...PDF Query Stuff

        $pdfUserEmail =  $pdfUser->email;
        $pdfUserName =  $pdfUser->first_name;

        //I WANT TO EMAIL THE AUTH USER HERE!!! Then Pass the Auth Users Name to the email.
        Mail::to($pdfUserEmail)
        ->send(new PdfFinished(
            $pdfUserName = $pdfUserName,
            ));
    }
}
```

**MAILABLE:**

```
class PdfFinished extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $pdfUserName;
    public $pdfpath;

    public function __construct($pdfUserName,$pdfpath)
    {
        $this->pdfUserName =$pdfUserName;
        $this->pdfpath =$pdfpath;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('PDF Has Completed')->markdown('emails.staff.pdfcompleted');
    }
}
```

**EMAIL TO AUTH USER:**

```
@component('mail::message')
### Hello {{ $pdfUserName }},<br>
..etc
@endcomponent
```

Been at this for days. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to access them using the `$this` keyword, as you have initialised them in the [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) of your job.

```
$pdfUserEmail = $this->pdfUser->email;
$pdfUserName = $this->pdfUser->first_name;
```

Also, `Auth::user()` returns an instance of App\User, so you don't need to do `User::find` as you already have a User model. So you can actually call your job like this:

`ProcessPdfHaiti::dispatch($haitiKids, Auth::user());`

Hope that helps :)

Comment: That worked great. Such a simple overlook on my part. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @echo no worries, all been there! Also added some extra info about using Auth::user() which you might find useful!

Comment: So if I used as you say `ProcessPdfHaiti::dispatch($haitiKids, Auth::user());` how would I pass `$pdfUser = User::find(Auth::user()->id);` from the Controller to the Job. I still need to pass `$pdfUser`.. correct?

Comment: @echo you won't need to create the variable `$pdfUser` as it is the exact same as `Auth::user()` - you only use this once so there's no need to assign this to a variable. You can just pass it in as the `Auth::user()` and your constructor will turn it into `$this->pdfUser` in your Job class

Comment: You can prove this by doing `dd($pdfUser);` and `dd(Auth::user())` - you will see that these are the same User object. You may as well save yourself one database query by using the User object given to you by Auth - saves you some time and processing power.

Comment: But yeah, you could also do `$pdfUser = Auth::user();` and pass it into your job like so `ProcessPdfHaiti::dispatch($haitiKids, $pdfUser);`

Comment: @party-ring What a great answer. but I wonder how it works. Can you explain why or give some reference?

Comment: @simpsons3 which part would you like explaining? :)

Comment: @party-ring I wonder why I put `Auth::user()` in the `construct` to make it work. I've read in some answers that in Queue, Laravel cannot access Session, but according to your answer, which worked, Session can be accessed via `construct()`. It make me confused.

Comment: @simpsons3 I'm not sure where in my answer I say to use the `Auth` facade in the constructor?

Comment: @party-ring, in your answer you said that `You need to access them using the $this keyword, as you have initialised them in the constructor of your job`, and in my case, I have initialized  `$user = Auth::user()` in constructor.